# Latent growth curve and cross-lagged panel modelling with 2 latent variables with 3 waves

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am trying to do latent growth curve modelling using lavaan on two latent variables with three time points. For each latent variable (EF and PEF), there are three indicators.

**1st problem:**

How do we specify individually varying time intervals? Participants come in every 6 months but realistically, some come after 5 months, some come after 8 months, ending up with individually varying time intervals.

I tried using

intP =~ 1*inh1+ 1*inh2 + 1*inh3 + 1*shif1 + 1*shif2 + 1*shif3 + 1*wm1 + 1*wm2 + 1*wm3

intE =~ 1*gs1+ 1*gs2 + 1*gs3 + 1*ss1 + 1*ss2 + 1*ss3 + 1*sop1 + 1*sop2 + 1*sop3

slopeP=~0*inh1+ inh2 + 1*inh3 + 0*shif1 + shif2 +1*shif3 + 0*wm1 + wm2 + 1*wm3

slopeE=~0*gs1 + gs2 + 1*gs3 + 0*ss1 + ss2 + 1*ss3 + 0*sop1 + sop2 + 1*sop3

- I wonder if this code interprets what I want to specify?

**2nd problem:** cross-lagged panel modelling for directionality

How do we specify the directionality (perhaps bi-directionality) between the two latent variables over time?

First of all, to figure out what the directionality will be like, I've done panel modelling. In the cross-lagged panel modelling context, I've tried to compare the 4 models:

a. no coupling

b. EF->PEF

c. PEF->EF

d. bidirectoinality - BUT I couldn't figure out how to specify the reciprocity.

What I've tried is to include both directions in one model. Is this right?

- PEF predicting EF

EF2+EF3 ~ PEF1

EF3 ~ PEF2

- EF predicting PEF

PEF2+PEF3 ~ EF1

PEF3 ~ EF2

**3rd problem**: Specifying the directionality in latent growth curve context?

I've tried:

intP ~~ intP

intE ~~ intE

slopeP ~~ slopeP

slopeE ~~ slopeE

intE ~~ slopeE

intE ~~ slopeP

slopeP ~~slopeE

Does this interpret what I mean? 
I want to see if:
a. intercept of EF predicts slope of EF and/or of PEF
b. intercept of PEF predicts slope of EF and/or of PEF
c. whether they are reciprocal or whether either of a or b is better fitting

**4th question:** Model not converging

So the last code is for random intercept, random slope model. But when I run the code, it doesn't converge - any suggestions as to why? I can think of sample-specific reasons (E.g., small/incomplete sample size) but anything else?

Thank you so much for any comments!!